# Comparing two mill i seconds in JavaScript to find out if dates are same

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out if two given milli seconds have same dates regardless of time...

This is what I am getting,

```
var getCurrentMS = Date.now();  // output : 1418825132083
var someDateMS = Date.Parse("17 December 2014 18:00");  // output: 1418839200000
```

now I want to compare both Milli seconds if it's today's date or not..

Comment: Set the hour, minutes and seconds to 0 and check to see if the date you're comparing to falls within 24 hours of that date.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that's not necessarily the same thing, though it might be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the timestamps to dates, and then check the year, month, and day values.

```
function sameDate(m1, m2) {
  var d1 = new Date(m1), d2 = new Date(m2);
  return d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
         d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
         d1.getDate() === d2.getDate();
}

console.log(sameDate(1418825132083, 1418839200000));
```

Comment: I would suggest `getUTC*` functions because the date objects may have differing timezones.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol well it *might* be right to do that, or it might not; it depends on the application. Two date objects constructed from two timestamp values in the same context will have the same offset. The question is whether the OP wants to see if the timestamps are for points in time in the same day in the local timezone, or in the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can cut milliseconds, even seconds. then cast two of them to int. so, this might work. and be careful about `Date.Parse`. it should be `Date.parse`.

```
var getCurrentMS = parseInt( Date.now() / (1000 * 60) );  
var someDateMS = parseInt (Date.parse("17 December 2014 18:00") / (1000 * 60) );  
var inSameHour = ( getCurrentMS == someDateMS);
```

if you want to check for days, you should cut times for day

```
var getCurrentMS = parseInt( Date.now() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );  
var someDateMS = parseInt (Date.parse("17 December 2014 18:00") / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );  
var inSameDay = ( getCurrentMS == someDateMS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
( ( (getCurrentMS - someDateMs) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 ) < 1) 
&& (getCurrentMS.getDay() === someDateMs.getDay() )
```

with this operation you would check if the difference is under 1 Day (24 hours) and if its not yet the next day.

It would return true if its the current day and false if its any other day.